# TCP flow control APIs in Android

Tags: android, android-networking, android-video-player, androidhttpclient

TCP flow control is used to control the rate of incoming data packets so that receiver of the traffic is not overwhelmed by the sender's rate. In other words, receiver can monitor this buffer size to indicate to the sender (or take some other actions) based on the current size of the buffer.

I want to know if Android provides an API to monitor, read this buffer? I am targeting to use these API to implement a android based client application (or a library) for adaptive http streaming. In adaptive streaming, client request for a different video chunk file based on the current bandwidth the client is experiencing. One of the approach to decide this bandwidth reading is flow control.

Any details or information in this context will be really useful. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting question. I'd remove the paragraph starting "Another factor that can be used to monitor bandwidth is to check the signal strength..." -- Signal strength is no indicator *at all* of bandwidth. You can be standing next to a cell-tower in the middle of nowhere and have GSM service, or you could be in the middle of the city, in a building, with one bar of RSSI, and have 4G.

Comment: Edited the question as per comment. I will post that aspect as another question.

Comment: Is this the class you are looking for? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html

Comment: Ultimately, Android will let an app with Internet permission do anything which a non-superuser owner of a socket can do under Linux.  Most of that has java APIs, but for anything which does not the underlying syscalls are all available to ndk libraries.